# SequelizeJS - why does my instance reload fail with "TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataValues' of null"

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am using a Sequelize model to store the logged-in user's information in a Node webapp. The `user` model is paranoid ([docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/instances/#destroying-deleting-persistent-instances)) and an instance is deleted if a user deactivates their account. When I try to reload a deactivated user instance it fails with the following TypeError. Why?

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataValues' of null
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/christo/repos/ticktrack/login-fiddle/src/server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/instance.js:723:20)
    at tryCatcher (/home/christo/repos/ticktrack/login-fiddle/src/server/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:24:31)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/christo/repos/ticktrack/login-fiddle/src/server/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:489:31)
    ...
```

**Detail**

Unsuccessful login attempts since the last successful login are tracked using a counter. This counter is incremented and then the user object is reloaded (to keep the webapp in sync with the DB) on each unsuccessful login. The relevant instance method is:

```
increment_unsuccessful_logins: function increment_unsuccessful_logins() {
  return this.increment({ unsuccessful_logins: 1})
    .then(this.reload.bind(this, undefined));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Binding the reload function to `this, {paranoid: false}` fixed the problem.

The TypeError was occurring because the instance being reloaded had been soft-deleted. When `reload` was called with no options (the `undefined` in its bind), the `find` that `reload` calls internally did not find any instance and returned null. In turn this caused the error message `TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataValues' of null`.

The updated function code:

```
    increment_unsuccessful_logins: function increment_unsuccessful_logins() {
      return this.increment({ unsuccessful_logins: 1})
        .then(this.reload.bind(this, { paranoid: false }));
    },
```